# Keep 3.13 kernel, update it, but no upgrades to newer kernels

Tags: kernel, updates

I want to keep the 3.13 kernel versions that are LTS with Trusty 14.04.2.  Updates to that kernel are OK and desired, but I don't want to upgrade to the 3.19 kernel as the HWE stack is no longer supported.  I don't want to upgrade to any of the 4.x kernels, as they bork my server from merely disabling Samba to not allowing it to boot at all. I would like to prevent the Software Updater from offering to upgrade to newer kernels.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just don't install the newer kernels?

Answer (score 1):

If your Ubuntu 14.04.x currently has the 3.13 kernel, it will not be upgraded to any other major version.

You can safely update the system.